# javascript - audio triggered by user inputs at fixed intervals

Tags: javascript, audio

In order to play `<audio>` according to certain `inputs`, I my `app` ends up with this `function`:

```
   function play_song() {

    var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.play();
}
```

now I need to determine the `global variable` `"input"`, i.e an `array` created with `events` triggered by the user:

```
    <textarea id="chat"> </textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="play_song();">talk</button>
```

I want to build up an `array` to store all the submitted words, but run the `input` only after a fixed interval. Is is possible?

Given the `function` below, am I on the right track?

```
   var input = function() {
           words = [];
           var chat = document.getElementById("chat").value.split("");
           words.push(chat);
           // setInterval(function(){}, 60000);
        }

   input();
```